# Faster Sudoku solver in C

Tags: c, performance, sudoku

I am writing a Sudoku solver in C, but am having problems with how long it takes to run. It can solve easier puzzles but once I put in one a little more difficult it runs and runs and never stops.

```
int solver (int x, int y)
{
  int a;
  int b;
  int i;
  int j;

  printf("Depth: %d\n", counter);

  for (a=1; a<10; a++)
  {  
    if (checkEverything(x, y, a))
    {
      board[x][y] = a;
      counter++;

      if (counter == 81)
      {
        return true;
      }

      if (counter > 200 || counter < -10) {
        return false;
      }

      for (i=0; i<9; i++)
      {
        for (j=0; j<9; j++)
        {
          if (board[i][j] == 0)
          {
            if (solver(i, j))
            {
              return true;
            }   
          }
        }
      }

      counter--;
      //printf("%d", a);      
    }
  }

  //printf("No Solution1");
  board[x][y] = 0;
  return false;
}
```

Comment: maybe threads help.

Comment: What is `checkEverything()`?

Comment: @parsaporahmad Why should threads make anything faster?

Comment: Please format your code correctly, even if it takes you 3 minutes more !

Comment: `if (     board[x][y] = a; xxx;`? (The code requires a bit more than just formatting)

Comment: @Till do you prefer to pick up 10 things with 1 hand while you have got two? so why should not threads make anything faster? do you believe in GPU?

Comment: Put a counter in and check how many guesses you are making. Mathemathics suggests this runs in the *billions*. Try to make a "hard" Sudoku into a "simple" one by first testing for easy solutions on rows, columns, and blocks, before going Brute Force.

Comment: I don't see any of the important parts here so I don't know why it's slow. If it takes more than a few seconds to solve a 9x9 sudoku, the algorithm is flawed. I did a sudoku solver (in java) that solves (one solution) all "hard" examples on wiki in one or two seconds, and human solvable (or at least by me) in a few milliseconds. It's based on a naive depth first search with backtracking, but the trick to get that to work is to calculate all "fixed" positions before going bananas with generating solution candidates.

Comment: [This is your algorithm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYM4QKMg12o). Now do you see why it takes so long? There are lots of web sites on writing a fast Sudoku solver. My articles on how to do so in C# are [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/graph+colouring/). You can adopt the algorithm described here to the language of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things that could be improved in this code.

### Post complete code

I understand that this code was migrated from Stack Overflow where the rules are a little different, but here on Code Review, we want to see not just one small piece but the whole code.  I can guess what `checkEveryting()` and `solver()` might do, but you'll get better reviews here by not making reviewers guess.

### Use a better algorithm

The fundamental problem with this code is that the algorithm is very inefficient.  Look at the **Related** panel to the right and you'll see more than a half dozen other similar programs.  Look over those to get ideas about how this might more efficiently be done.

### Make the formatting consistent

The code currently include this:

```
  if (counter == 81)
  {
    return true;
  }

  if (counter > 200 || counter < -10) {
    return false;
  }
```

In one case, the opening `{` is on the same line, and in the other it's on the next line.  It's a small thing, but it's useful to choose a convention and stick with it.

### Avoid the use of global variables

I see that `counter` and `board` are declared as global variables rather than as local variables. It's generally better to explicitly pass variables your function will need rather than using the vague implicit linkage of a global variable.

### Use meaningful variable names

The variable names `a`, and `b` are not at all descriptive. Better naming makes your code easier to read, understand and maintain.

### Eliminate unused variables

Unused variables are a sign of poor code quality, so eliminating them should be a priority.  In this code, `b` is declared but never actually used.  My compiler also tells me that.  Your compiler is probably also smart enough to tell you that, if you ask it to do so.